# Effectively combining logical conditions inside a list using AND

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

Data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [(1, 8, 1, None),
        (1, 1, 8, None),
        (2, 1, 8, None),
        (2, 8, 8, 9999)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
```

List of conditions:

```py
conditions = [
    ((F.col('c1') == 2) | (F.col('c2') < 5)),
    ((F.col('c3') == 1) | F.col('c4').isNotNull())
]
```

Filter to rewrite:

```py
df = df.filter(conditions[0] & conditions[1])

df.show()
#  +---+---+---+----+
#  | c1| c2| c3|  c4|
#  +---+---+---+----+
#  |  2|  8|  8|9999|
#  +---+---+---+----+
```

In my original data I have an undefined number of conditions in the list. I'm looking for a way to combine them  all using AND, so that I wouldn't need to reference them individually using index numbers.

I've unsuccessfully tried Python's built-in `all()`:
`df = df.filter(all(conditions))`

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's `reduce` function.

```
from functools import  reduce

df_result = reduce(lambda dfx, i: dfx.filter(conditions[i]), range(len(conditions)), df)
```

though it seems like a recursive operation, Spark will optimize the execution by combining those filters with AND operators.

```
df_result.explain(False) # set to True for details

# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Filter (((c1#0L = 2) OR (c2#1L < 5)) AND ((c3#2L = 1) OR isnotnull(c4#3L)))
# +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[c1#0L,c2#1L,c3#2L,c4#3L]
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a really nice option. I didn't know Spark would optimize the `reduce` function.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `df = df.filter(reduce(lambda i, j: i & j, conditions))`

Answer (score 0):

One way is by translating conditions into pure Spark and then using `' AND '.join()`:

```
conditions = [
    '((c1 = 2) OR (c2 < 5))',
    '((c3 = 1) OR isnotnull(c4))'
]

df = df.filter(' AND '.join(conditions))
```